# Can't Use Variable in PHP If Statement

Tags: php, variables, content-management-system, global-variables

I'm having trouble using a variable for the directory name in this PHP `if` statement:

```
if (($handle = opendir("news"))) {
    // Read all file from the actual directory
    while ($file = readdir($handle))  {
        if (!is_dir($file)) {
            $fileList[] = $file;
        }
    }
}
```

When I use a variable (`$newsDir`) instead of a string literal for the directory name (`"news"`), the script stops working.

```
$newsDir = $_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT] . "edit/news";
var_dump(file_exists($newsDir));
// bool(true)
var_dump(is_dir($newsDir));
// bool(true)
var_dump($newsDir);
// string(36) "/f5/jb-cms-testing/public//edit/news"
if (($handle = opendir($newsDir))) {
    // Read all file from the actual directory
    while ($file = readdir($handle))  {
        if (!is_dir($file)) {
            $fileList[] = $file;
        }
    }
}
```

It doesn't throw any errors, the function just doesn't properly run. At first, I thought it was because my `$newsDir` variable is `$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT] . "edit/news"`, but even if I set `$newsDir` to just `"news"`, it doesn't work. So it's something to do with the fact that I'm using a variable, as far as I can tell.

Any ideas why? Also, this is the only place, and the only file that `$handle` occurs, so I'm not sure why it works at all. It was a while ago that I built this, and I was using a tutorial, so I'm not sure exactly how it works. It's basically just a way to sort files in the `news` directory.

Comment: Please edit your question to show a *complete* test-case.

Comment: Please show the output of `var_dump($newsDir);`

Comment: You could try [`scandir()`](http://php.net/scandir) or [`glob()`](http://php.net/glob) which don't incur the handle overhead.

Comment: Also enable `error_reporting()`. And you might just lack a `/` separator between DOCUMENT_ROOT and  the local path fragment.

Comment: Please show the output of `var_dump(file_exists($newsDir), is_dir($newsDir));`

Comment: Is opendir returning false?  var_dump($handle) will tell you, after it has ran.

Comment: Off-topic: when an assignment appears in a condition, it isn't clear whether this was intended or is a typo. A common convention is to wrap assignments in an extra pair of parentheses to signify that it's intentional: `if (($handle = ...))`.

Comment: output of `var_dump(file_exists($newsDir), is_dir($newsDir));`: `bool(true) bool(true)`

Comment: Output of `var_dump($newsDir);`: `string(36) "/f5/jb-cms-testing/public//edit/news"`

Comment: But it doesn't matter what the variable is, even if it's just "news", exactly like it is in the first bit code, it stops working.

Comment: please recheck your entire code and related file. Make sure error reporting is enabled: ini_set('error_reporting',E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors',1);

Comment: @Rev: please update the question with the variable values. In general, respond to requests for clarifications by updating your post, rather than replying with a comment. For one thing, a question should be understandable without reading comments. For another, SO is a QA & site, not a forum, and comments aren't intended (nor are they well suited) for discussions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow. I figured it out. It's just that you apparently can't use variables out side of a function. I was including the vars.php file outside of the function, which was causing the error. I have no idea why you wouldn't be able to do this, maybe someone can enlighten me?

Thanks for all the input.

Comment: SO is a Q&A site, not a forum. If you have a new question, first search to make sure it hasn't been answered before and, if it hasn't, post a new question.

Comment: I always do search. I couldn't find an answer because it's a pretty noob question (I didn't know to search for "using variables outside of a function" since that was the answer). I know it's not a forum, I was answering my own question, not replying to it. I try and mark things as answered whenever I can, even if I have to submit the answer myself.

Comment: I was referring to where you ask a question within your answer, not the part where you answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following to check where the error is (example from php.net)

```
<?php
// Report all PHP errors
error_reporting(-1);

$dir = $_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT] . "edit/news";
if (is_dir($dir)) {
    if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
            $fileList[] = $file;
            echo "filename: $file : filetype: " . filetype($dir . $file) . "read \n";
        }
        closedir($dh);
    }
}
?>
```